# Unresolved inclusion eigen3/Eigen/Geometry

Tags: eclipse, geometry, eigen

I have this problem:

unresolved inclusion:

I am working with Eclipse and I typed :

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Geometry>
```

I checked Project->Properties and this is what I have is this:

[image]

So I think it should be included. What is going on with eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into C/C++ General -> Indexer, and be sure to tick:

- Enable project specific settings
- Index unused headers as C++ files

This should solve your issue.

Comment: This worked. But I suggest you guys to try to include this kind of libraries through your CMakeLists.txt file (if you are using CMake) or through your Makefile if you are using Make.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse tries to include by default the .h files of the library but those are not sufficient to build the project correctly. As done by default by Eclipse for the stdlib, substitution rules need to be used in order for Eclipse to automatically handle includes correctly.

Go to Preferences > C/C++ > Coding Style > Organize Includes > Header Substitution, There you can add a new rule, and import the `eigen-header-substitution.xml` file.

Please reference http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=IDEs.